# Issues while printing float values

Tags: c++, c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
int main()
{
   float i = 2.5;
   printf("%d\n%d\n%d",i,i,i);
}
```

When I compile this using gcc and run it, I get this as the output:

```
0
1074003968
0
```

Why doesn't it print just

```
2
2
2
```

Comment: You probably also want to compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra`. GCC complains about `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’` when I compile that code with the warnings turned on.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505146/why-is-x-and-y-always-0-with-a-float

Comment: Because you lied to printf(). You told it there would be 3 ints but gave it 3 floats.

Answer (score 12):

You're passing a `float` (which will be converted to a `double`) to `printf`, but telling `printf` to expect an `int`. The result is undefined behavior, so at least in theory, anything could happen.

What will *typically* happen is that `printf` will retrieve `sizeof(int)` bytes from the stack, and interpret whatever bit pattern they hold as an `int`, and print out whatever value that happens to represent.

What you almost certainly want is to cast the `float` to `int` before passing it to `printf`.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what happens instead of just saying "use `%f`".

Answer (score 2):

The `"%d"` format specifier is for decimal integers.  Use `"%f"` instead.

And take a moment to read the [`printf()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 1):

The "%d" is the specifier for a decimal integer (typically an 32-bit integer) while the "%f" specifier is used for decimal floating point. (typically a double or a float).

if you only want the non-decimal part of the floating point number you could specify the precision as 0.

i.e.

```
float i = 2.5;
printf("%.0f\n%.0f\n%.0f",i,i,i);
```

note you could also cast each value to an int and it would give the same result.

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d",int(i),int(i),int(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`%d` prints decimal `(int)`s, not `(float)`s.  `printf()` cannot tell that you passed a `(float)` to it (C does not have native objects; you cannot ask a value what type it is); you need to use the appropriate format character for the type you passed.